# Azure cognitive search, How to define which field are used to identify if document is identical?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, langchain

**It just works now.** Don't ask me why, I guess I made a mistake when originally testing the code. Sorry for bothering you! Here the issue for historic reasons:

I have a cognitive search vector database. In this database there are documents that have a content (plain text) and a session_id (unique string). When I add a new document to the database that has the same content as an existing file but a different session_id, the document is added and for all documents in the databases with the same content, the session_id is updated.
It seems that when I add documents to the database using the 'update' setting, the differences in the session_id are ignored when searching for identical documents.
How can I change this behaviour?

Note:

- Ideally i do not want to change the content of my files, rather only change how cognitive search decides if a new document is identical.
- I do not want to change to the 'mergeOrUpload' setting, as I am using the session id field to filter my similarity search result. And for now only Filter, not Search is possible using azure cognitive search as a tool within Langchain.

Here is how i currently define the index.

```
        embedding_function = embedding_model.embed_query
        fields = [
            SimpleField(
                name="id",
                type=SearchFieldDataType.String,
                key=True,
                filterable=True,
            ),
            SearchableField(
                name="content",
                type=SearchFieldDataType.String,
            ),
            SearchField(
                name="content_vector",
                type=SearchFieldDataType.Collection(SearchFieldDataType.Single),
                searchable=True,
                vector_search_dimensions=len(embedding_function("test")),
                vector_search_configuration="default",
            ),
            SearchableField(
                name="metadata",
                type=SearchFieldDataType.String
            ),
        ]
        if session_id is not None:
            fields.append(SimpleField(
                name="session_id",
                type=SearchFieldDataType.String,
                filterable=True
            ))
        vector_store: AzureSearch = AzureSearch(
            azure_search_endpoint=f"https://{os.getenv('AZURE_COGNITIVE_SEARCH_SERVICE_NAME')}.search.windows.net",
            azure_search_key=os.getenv("AZURE_COGNITIVE_SEARCH_API_KEY"),
            # index_name=os.getenv("AZURE_COGNITIVE_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME"),
            index_name=f"{database_name}-index",
            embedding_function=embedding_function,
            search_type="similarity",
            fields=fields,
        )
```

To add documents i do:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredFileLoader, UnstructuredURLLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter

source = "https://www.tagesschau.de/wissen/technologie/ki-klickarbeiter-trainingsdaten-100.html"

loader = UnstructuredURLLoader([source], strategy="auto", **kwargs)

# split data in pages
documents = loader.load_and_split()

# add metadata to each page
for doc in documents:
    doc.metadata.update({'source': source, "doc_id": doc_id})
    # add session_id to metadata if available, necessary for Azure Cognitive Search filtering
    if session_id is not None:
        doc.metadata.update({"session_id": session_id})

text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
    separator="\n",
    chunk_size=1000,
    chunk_overlap=200,
    length_function=len,
)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

vector_store.add_documents(texts)
```

When I run this twice times for the same source but with two different session ids, i have the documents/texts two times in the database, but the session_id is identical in all duplicates.

I receive the entries in the db similar to this:

```
        results = vector_store.client.search(
            search_text="",
            vector=np.array(vector_store.embedding_function(""), dtype=np.float32).tolist(),
            top_k=max(vector_store.client.get_document_count(), 1),
            vector_fields="content_vector",
        )
```

This is how a typical entry looks:

```
{'id': 'NGI2YmE5OTUtZTFhNC00ZmYyLTgwYjQtYjU2OGEzMDY1Y2Yy', 'content': 'interview ... mit einer Internetverbindung anmelden kann.', 
'content_vector': [0.2,0.8 ...], 
'metadata': '{"source": "https://www.tagesschau.de/wissen/technologie/ki-klickarbeiter-trainingsdaten-100.html", "doc_id": "2a0555837ec164aa9911c09e04d0c78e", "session_id": "4a0885a7816742f0a7ea98ebf25eb663"}'
'session_id': '4a0885a7816742f0a7ea98ebf25eb663'}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you give more details on the output you are getting and expected output, search queries you are using, code and reference. That can help in reproduce the issue?